# C# User Control that can contain other Controls (when using it)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I found something about this issue for ASP, but it didn't help me much ...

What I'd like to do is the following: I want to create a user control that has a collection as property and buttons to navigate through this collection. I want to be able to bind this user control to a collection and display different controls on it (containing data from that collection). 
Like what you had in MS Access on the lower edge of a form ...

to be more precise:

When I actually use the control in my application (after I created it), I want to be able to add multiple controls to it (textboxes, labels etc) between the `<myControly>` and `</mycontrol>` 
If I do that now, the controls on my user control disappear.

Comment: whats the problem? This sounds very easy to do...

Comment: The problem is not the collection and the navigation buttons but the thing that I want to be able to add controls to the User Control when I use it in another application.

Comment: If I try to put multiple controls between <myControly> and </mycontrol> theres an error that I can put only one control there. If I try a grid, the controls on my custom control disappear.

Comment: I'd like to see the code to do it.  If I follow MAD9 correctly, he wants a user control, where part of the content is static, but it also has a section where you can add controls from the parent Window XAML.

Comment: Thank you guys very much so far! 2 things: I'm no native english speaker, so please forgive me my probably imprecise description of the actual problem. I didn't know that there was such a thing as an item control, so I will check out what that thing can do. If its not, what I need I will try Nirs solution (or maybe both so I can learn something). Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example of one way to do what you want:

First, the code - UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent", typeof(object), typeof(UserControl1));


    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object MyContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And the user control's XAML - UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="InCtrl.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300" Name="MyCtrl">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Up"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=MyCtrl, Path=MyContent}"/>
        <Button Content="Down"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And finally, the xaml to use our wonderful new control:

```
<Window x:Class="InCtrl.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:me="clr-namespace:InCtrl"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <me:UserControl1>
            <me:UserControl1.MyContent>
                <Button Content="Middle"/>
            </me:UserControl1.MyContent>
        </me:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @Nir +1
I was playing around with this same solution, but I couldn't quite get it working -- I was missing the Binding on the content presenter's content property.

Comment: also consider this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017421/access-like-data-navigation-in-wpf

this is the solution I finally implemented. Its not even necessary that the control contains other controls as I noticed.

Comment: This answer helped me solve the `Cannot create an instance of "UIElementCollection"` error for a control that contains other controls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but I think what you're describing is an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) using [`DataTemplates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) to display the contents of (presumably) an [ObservableCollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: Your answer is more exactly what I needed (I believe), but Nirs solution does more exactly what I described above. Since only one answer is possible I ticked his one. But I'm currently evaluating what a Items control can do and it seems that ist pretty much what I had in mind (with a few customizations). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A UserControl may not be the best way to do this. You're wanting to add decorations around content, which is basically what Border does: it has a child element, and it adds its own stuff around the edges.

Look into the Decorator class, which Border descends from. If you make your own Border descendant, you should be easily able to do what you want. However, I believe this would require writing code, not XAML.

You might still want to make a UserControl to wrap the buttons at the bottom, just so you can use the visual designer for part of the process. But Decorator would be a good way to glue the pieces together and allow for user-definable content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.aspx) to a built-in control (`HeaderedContentControl`) that does the same thing as the accepted answer except that it is an existing control in WPF since .Net 3.0