# 'Cannot create an instance of' error in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a public class

```
public class FCabinetNames:List<string>

{
    BusinessLogic admintasks = new BusinessLogic();
    public FCabinetNames()
    {
        try
        {
            List<CabinetData> cab1 = admintasks.CabinetDataforGrid();
            foreach (var c1 in cab1)
            {
                this.Add(c1.CabinetName);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the xaml page when i try to add this class as a static resource i get the 'cannot create instance of' as below 
[image]

Please guide.

UPDATE :

An important point i missed telling. The application compiles fine and the xaml page also loads fine. I was planing to use this as a datasource and expectedly that remains blank.

Comment: 1. show your xaml. 2. is XAML file resolving the namespaces for this class correctly?

Comment: @dennis morozov : Yes it is resolving correctly. Please see the xmlns:header on top part of image. FCabinetnames as you can see is a public class in namespace Gage_Seelctor_UI.

Comment: Do you have the same error at runtime?

Comment: Is it possible that `new BusinessLogic()` throws an exception? It's the only part outside the catch-all block.

Comment: @Alberto : There are no runtime errors and it compiles fine

Comment: @Heinzi: new BusinessLogic() should not throw an exception.Initially I was afraid it had to do with some error in constructor so put the try..catch to prevent anything breaking. But then as long as it compiles fine it should not stop from referencing. right ?

Comment: @samba: The reference is fine, and it compiles fine. The problem is that WPF cannot *instantiate* it, which (probably) means that some exception is thrown during *instantiation*. `BusinessLogic admintasks = new BusinessLogic();` is the only part of the instantiation logic that is not protected by your try-catch. I suggest that you try to move it into the constructor, i.e. just declare `BusinessLogic admintasks;` outside the constructor and assign the value *inside*. Don't forget to recompile afterwards.

Comment: I had this error when trying to create a custom control that can by used in XAML to enclose other controls.  This answer helped eliminate this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/970560/748064.

Answer (score 12):

I've had similar issues in the past. Most of the time its components and references that your custom class is trying to load.

The two step solution that works most often for me:

1. Move the constructor of your custom class to another function, then call that function in in the constructor of your list (or class)
2. Add the following before the function call in the constructor but after the Initialize component. (I use this for user controls and isn't really valid in your case, but depending on how you set stuff up. It could be useful)

---

```
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
return;
```

Both steps help the xaml designer from loading components that may have issues with the being in a debug state.
@Heinzi is pretty much spot on with "something" throwing errors, usually (in my experience) its something buried that you wouldn't expect.

Comment: updated with actual fix to mark as answer after edit is approved.

Comment: This helped resolve my case! Really appreciate your help!